# Image overlapped with Kinect

Tags: ros, kinect, image

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm new in ROS and this is my first question, so I don't know if I'm going to ask a silly question. I've looked a lot of tutorials and other asked questions and thanks to that I've solved a lot of my doubts, but I'm still having problems.

My purpose: obtain a point cloud from a Kinect mounted in a robot. So far, I have mounted the camera based on the one of the PR2. Using rosbag, I've recorded the data from the rgb and the depth topics. Then, using rxbag, I can visualize perfectly the rgb's images, but when I try to do the same with the depth, I got an overlapped and displaced image. I don't know how to explain it better. Here you have what I get: http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg337/scaled.php?server=337&filename=pr2depth.jpg&res=landing

And here's what I get with the rgb's topic: http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg406/scaled.php?server=406&filename=pr2rgb.jpg&res=landing

I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or if whats I see is correct.

I'm using Fuerte in Ubuntu 12.04

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38084/image-overlapped-with-kinect/) by [g.aterido](https://answers.ros.org/users/2783/g.aterido/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2012-07-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The gray-wrapping effect is OK as it tries to display depth data as image data. The repeat seems odd to me, but is maybe an effect of the simulator or the display doesn't like depth-images?

You should try to visualize the point cloud in rviz. If that is correct the rest should only be display errors. Possibly the image display in rviz is also displaying the depth-image without repeat.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1